# Do php include files have to re-declare html tags?

Tags: php, html, include

Simple question here..

An observation that I've made from different tutorials (about using includes).. are that people frequently redeclare  tags in included files.

Here is an example.

**Index.php**

```
<?php
include 'header.html.php';
include 'content.html.php';
include 'footer.html.php';
```

**header.html.php**

```
<html>
<head> All head stuff <head>
<body>
```

**content.html.php**

```
<html>
<head></header
<body>
//content
</body>
</html>
```

**footer.html.php**

```
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a reason for including the whole html formatting in the include file? Is it required?
Thanks

Comment: Seems like an anti-pattern to me.  The browser may forgive this and display the intended output (some browsers may, at least), but it's still very incorrect to include those elements multiple times.  Any behavior resulting from this incorrect markup would be undefined at best, and would need to be corrected before debugging any further problems (such as malfunctioning CSS/JavaScript).

Comment: That's a relief.. it seamed really illogical!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `content.html.php` file should *not* have the redundant HTML code that is contained in the header and footer files. In fact, that defeats the purpose of having them as they are meant to include the common header and footer code for you so you explicitly do not have to put in in the body of the content pages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what tutorials you're reading, but they are the wrong ones! Look at the source outputted in the browser. Multiple HTML tags is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If you understand that, you get your answer.

I recommend you do like that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <?php include'head.html.php') ?>
</head>
<body>
  <?php include'header_navigation.html.php') ?>

  <?php include'content.html.php') ?>

  <?php include 'footer.html.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**head.html.php**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Your website title</title>
```

**header_navigation.html.php**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**content.html.php**

```
<section>
  <article>
    <h1>Your content title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, quos, saepe a similique totam excepturi enim natus voluptatum rerum eum veritatis aspernatur minus ipsum accusamus voluptate minima quis suscipit officia!</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

**footer.html.php**

```
<!-- your scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  });
</script>
```